# how to submit radio button values to database using xampp

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, xampp

I am trying to submit the radio button values which have been selected to the database, but i am unable to do that.
Can anyone help me out please?

I went through youtube videos, still i didn't understand what do i really need to do about it.
At first i thought i need to put an id to the radio buttons but later when i went through other posts, i got more and more confused.

I did successfully link the form to the database, when i click on submit it does posts all the input values but it won't put the gender radio input to the database.

Please help.
Your time and help will be highly appreciated!

first.html->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+SC|Merienda" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>  
  <style> 

  h1{
  color: #27292b !important;
  font-family: "Alegreya+SC";
  opacity: 0.85;


  }

  </style>


<title>Innoccura Technologies Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body style="background:url(Work.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 120%">

<div align="center">

<form id="myForm" name="form1" action="" method="post"> 

<table >

<h1 align="center"> Innoccura Technologies Form Submission </h1>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <td style=color:white;><b>First Name:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" class="form-control" name="t1"  id="name"></td>
    </div>
    </tr>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>   



    <tr>

        <div class="form-group">

        <td style=color:white;><b>Last Name:</b></td>

        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" class="form-control" name="t0" id="lname"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td style=color:white;><b>Mobile Number:</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="Enter your mobile no." class="form-control" name="num" id="numb"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style=color:white;><b>gender</b></td>
        <td>  
              <input type="radio"  name="g"   value="male"> Male
              <input type="radio"  name="g"  value="female"> Female<br>
        </td>

    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style=color:white;><b>City :</b></td>
        <td>
            <select id="city" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
              <option value="New York">New York</option>
              <option value="Detroit">Detroit</option>
              <option value="Ladson">Ladson</option>
            </select>
        </td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>


<tr>
<td style=color:white;><b>Enter Age</b></td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your age" name="t3" id="t3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>
<tr>
<td style=color:white;><b>Address:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" id="address"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="button" class="form-control" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="aa();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:20px"></td>

    </tr>

</div>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
function aa()
{
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?nm="+document.getElementById("name").value+"&lt="+document.getElementById("lname").value+"&mb="+document.getElementById("numb").value+"&citi="+document.getElementById("city").value+"&age="+document.getElementById("t3").value+"&address="+document.getElementById("address").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);

}


</script>



</body>
</html>

<?php


if($_POST["submit"]=="submit")
{
$gender = $_POST["g"];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    $s="insert into tester(gender) values('".$gender."')";

    if(mysql_query($s))
        echo "Record Saved";
    else
        echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

This is the code for insert.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitle Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">



</head>
<body>
<?php

$nm=$_GET["nm"];
$lastname=$_GET["lt"];
$mobileNumber=$_GET["mb"];
//$gender=$_GET["gen"];
//$gender=$_GET["gend"];

$gender = $_POST["g"];
$city=$_GET["citi"];
$age=$_GET["age"];
$address=$_GET["address"];

var_dump($nm);
var_dump($lastname);
var_dump($mobileNumber);
var_dump($gender);
var_dump($city);
var_dump($age);
var_dump($address);

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tester VALUES('$nm','$lastname','$mobileNumber','$gender','$city','$age','$address')");



?>
</body>

</html>
```

I googled a lot but i couldn't understand the concept on sending the input of radio buttons to the database.

Please Help.

Comment: XAMPP hasen't really to do anything with your problem. Btw, please stop using `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` instead. Also, learn about SQL injection at http://bobby-tables.com - right now, your code is really vulnerable and not save at all. Your database could be hacked within a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge about your system. Also, please learn the difference between `GET` and `POST` method

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting value of radio `g` in query string of your http request.This is the first mistake.

And
when you will include it, it will be a GET method of passing data to server, so use $_GET instead $_POST.

```
$gender = $_GET["g"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a radio button and click on a submit button, you need to handle the submission of any selected values in your php code using $_POST[] For example: if your radio button is:

```
 <input type="radio" name="rdb" value="male"/>
```

then in your php code you need to use:

```
  $rdb_value = $_POST['rdb'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['g'])) { $gender=$_REQUEST['g']; else{ $gender=""; }
```